# ¿Cómo hacer que un método no continúe hasta que se cierre un AlertDialog en Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, alertdialog

Tengo el siguiente código de `Xamarin.Android` para cuando apreto un botón:

```
private void BtnConfirma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rta = ws.ConfirmaControl(); //Esta es una llamada a un WebService que devuelve un string...

    if (rta != "OK"){
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
        ad.SetTitle("Error!");
        ad.SetMessage("Se produjo un error");
        ad.SetButton("OK", delegate
        {
            return;
        });
        ad.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        ad.Show();
    }
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuPrincipal));
    StartActivity(intent);
    FinishAffinity();
}
```

La idea es que si la respuesta del `WebService` no es "OK" me muestre una alerta informando el error, pero que de todas maneras continúe.
El problema que tengo es que me muestra la alerta y al instante me manda a la otra pantalla, sin darme tiempo a leer el mensaje que me muestra.

¿Hay forma de hacer que el método no continúe hasta que aprete el botón del `AlertDialog`?

Comment: tal vez esto ayude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967341/xamarin-android-make-a-modal-window-that-waits-like-messagebox-show-from-c-sha

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!